# « C'est vous qui devez vous taire » ou « c'est vous qui devez se taire » ?

Tags: grammaire, infinitif, verbes-pronominaux

Pouvez-vous me montrer la phrase correcte ? En donnant une explication ce sera encore mieux.

Answer (score 4):

Le pronom réfléchi ou réflexif des verbes pronominaux s'accorde avec la personne, même à l'infinitif.

> Je veux *me* coucher.
>
> Tu n'arrivais pas à *te* décider.
>
> Il a fait attention à ne pas *se* blesser.
>
> Nous voulons *nous* rencontrer.
>
> Vous devez *vous* entraider.
>
> Ils estiment *s'*en être bien sortis.

Dans l'exemple donné il faut donc dire :

> C'est vous qui devez *vous* taire.